# Error converting Java HashMap to Scala Array[Object] generating JasperReport

Tags: scala, jasper-reports

I'm trying to implement JasperReport generation in Scala. I need to take the information from memory and merge it with the report.

This is what the documentation says, in Java:

```
HashMap[] reportDataSource = new HashMap[4];
// fill reportDataSource with information
JRMapArrayDataSource dataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(reportDataSource);
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream,
                                       new HashMap(), dataSource);
```

This is my attempt in Scala, where I get a compilation error in the line noted below:

```
val row1 = HashMap[String,String]("code" -> "B1", "name" -> "Bank 1")
val row2 = HashMap[String,String]("code" -> "B2", "name" -> "Bank 2")
val map = Array[HashMap[String,String]](row1,row2)  

val reportDataSource = new JRMapArrayDataSource(map)  // <-- this line does not compile

val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(blob.getBinaryStream, baos, params, reportDataSource)
Ok(baos.toByteArray).as("application/pdf")
```

The error (cannot convert from HashMap to Array[Object]):

> type mismatch; found :
>   Array[scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String]] required:
>   Array[Object] Note: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,String] <:
>   Object, but class Array is invariant in type T. You may wish to
>   investigate a wildcard type such as _ <: Object. (SLS 3.2.10)>

How to do the conversion and fix the problem?

Comment: One thing that might work is to change the type of the array variable.  As in val map = Array[Object](row1,row2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very easily fix your error:
`val map = Array[Object](row1,row2)`

The reason why your code did not compile in the first place, is that the type of map value is `Array[HashMap[String, String]]`, while method only accepts `Array[Object]` (I recommend you to read about variance, but it is not important in the case of this problem).

On the other hand i assume that your code will still fail in runtime, because you are using scala HashMaps, while method you use probably requires java hash-maps

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using java.util.HashMap, it worked perfectly.